# Has Batman Ever Sacrificed himself for Superman?

Tags: comics, dc, superman, batman, dc-animated-universe

Has Batman ever sacrificed himself to save Supes? Or come close with intention? I was curious if he had!

Any universe, but comic source preferred and encouraged.. Thanks!

Comment: @cde haha, well I don't know what to say to that. I just thought it was an interesting hypothetical that I hadn't thought of before. Granted with the length of comics it's probably been done.

Comment: A better phrasing of the question is just "Has Batman ever taken a bullet for,  or pretended to die, to save someone else's life".

Comment: I'd be happy to change it if you'll give me a minute!

Comment: The answer as to whether Batman would sacrifice himself to save Superman  depends on whether Batman knows he is a comic book character.  If he does, then he knows that comic book characters don't stay dead, so he can choose to save Superman or not, because whoever dies won't be dead for very long anyway. :)

Comment: In the movies, Batman SPOILER ALERT sacrifices himself at the end of *The Dark Knight Rises*, in a tragic, doomed attempt to make people care about *Man of Steel*.

Comment: I like to think that Batman would find a third option. Randomly deciding to sacrifice himself is more of Superman's shtick.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JlMhk1_7Ww. Enjoy people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes

**...not in comic books (as far as I know), but in the animated film *Superman/Batman: Public Enemies*.**

[image]

From the plot summary at the [Batman Wiki](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Superman/Batman:_Public_Enemies):

> Toyman has built a rocket to stop the meteor, the appearance of which is that of a giant, robotic Composite Superman. Lex arrives to stop the launch and kill Superman, disabling the remote guidance systems. **Batman volunteers to fly it himself, despite Superman's protests. Though initially faring poorly against Lex, Superman flies into a rage after seeing his best friend sacrifice himself, easily tearing apart Lex's suit.** Batman, meanwhile, succeeds in destroying the meteor, surviving thanks to a small lifeboat built into the rocket. Superman carries the craft back to Earth.

In the end, Batman survives, but he definitely intended to sacrifice himself.

Comment: Dang, I was thinking of PE too but didnt think it applied. Time to rewatch it

Comment: @cde : It's one of the good ones, even though it was direct-to-dvd.

Comment: Nah, doesn't count. He totally knew that Superman would save him. Just like he totally knew about the rocket's lifeboat. You think Batman would actually fly up in that thing without having memorized the schematics?

Answer (score 5):

A few times. The two that come to my mind are:

1. The animated movie **Superman/Batman: Public Enemies**, where

   > Batman hijacks a "rocket" and rams a Kryptonite meteor with it to prevent it hitting Earth, sacrificing himself in place of Superman.
2. And the Justice League Unlimited cartoon, episode **The Doomsday Sanction**:

   > **Batman**: Nothing? What if Luthor does become President, like he did in their world? What would stop you from doing what that Superman did? 
   >   **Superman**: There's always that Kryptonite you carry around.
   >   **Batman**: You don't get to joke! Not today. I just took a bullet for you.

I don't remember if it ever happened in the comics, though. Most likely.

Answer (score 3):

In *Injustice: Year 3*, issues 12-14, Superman is put to sleep via some magic powder.

When he sleeps, he sees the world as he would like it to be; in this world, Batman snaps Joker's neck and turns himself in.

[image]

[image]

After asked why, he says that he did it to protect Superman and his family.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the finale of "Justice League" (before it became "Justice League Unlimited"), Batman piloted the Watchtower on a collision course with the Thanagarian gate fully intending to sacrifice himself for everyone on the planet (including Superman); he didn't expect to survive because the rest of the League was busy fighting the Thanagarians and wouldn't get to him in time, and he needed to maintain control so there was no way for him to make an escape in time. He only got away because Superman *did* manage to reach him in time and get him out just before impact.